# Can electricity transfer radioactivity?

Tags: electricity, radioactivity

If a cable used to power something is exposed to a radioactive source will it over time make the entire cable radioactive?

Comment: What do you mean by "make wire radioactive"? You mean that the wire itself would become a source of radioactivity? In that case the answer is *no* unless the wire itself is made of radioactive material. But I suppose you mean normal electrical wire.

Comment: yes I mean normal electrical wire. if the answer is no I will accept it if you add your comment as a reply.

Comment: Yes, of course!

That is why so called "nuclear power filters" are sold to people. 

You should install such a filter asap where the power cable enters Your house.

Comment: no, but perhaps the inverse is true "radioactivity can transfer electricity"

Comment: @HDE: That'd actually make quite an interesting question by itself

Comment: if you worry about radiactivity flowing out through cables, you worry not: you don't have to look further than the ocean in front of fukushima to see that radiactivity will flow out much more efficiently through the ocean

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are you worried that the cables that go to the Fukushima reactors will carry radioactivity out?

The answer is No. You should [read up a bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radioactivity) on radioactivity and educate yourself, since it is one of the facts of life. In the article you will see that it is atoms that are responsible for radioactivity whereas the current in the cables is due to electrons. The parts of the cables that are in a radiation environment will become radioactive, but that activity will remain in the locality, and the length of cable that was exposed. It in no way can be transmitted away from the region the way the current is transmitted.

Comment: there is no mention in the question about the Fukushima, so why mention it in answer?

Comment: thanks for the link, very interesting, I was curious about the topic but didn't know where to begin to look

Comment: "atoms are responsible for radioactivity and electrons for electricity" (rephrased) Don't get this (in general, not related with this particular question). E.g beta radiation can be only electrons. And the electrons to generate electricity come from atoms so I really don't understand this differentiation...

Comment: @Ixxzz  electricity is a general fuzzy term. Current needs mobile carriers, and in metals these are the electrons. The atoms are immobile and it is the nuclei of the atoms that can become radioactive. Beta radiation releases electrons but at random directions and not enough to build up a current in a conductor.

Answer (score 3):

Electricity is the movement of electrons. Electrons cannot become radioactive. So a current in the cable will not change the radioactivity of the cable.

Comment: But in the original question a cable exposed to a radioactive source could become radioactive - whether used to power something or not

Comment: @Martin: as you say. The point I want to make is that the current will not alter the radioactivity.

Comment: And in either case, the radioactivity will not migrate down the wire.

Answer (score 3):

A cable cannot transport radioactivity away from the reactor using electrical current as a transport mechanism.

Nevertheless - if a material is exposed to a source of particles of sufficiently high energy (high energy particle beam, or neutron beam, for instance), the material can become activated (meaning that some of the atoms in the material will become radioactive), and may remain activated for a very long time, so use of materials that had been previously used in particle beam applications must be carefully considered.

So, the answer is yes, in the sense that material can become radioactive from exposure to high energy particles as one would find in a reactor/particle beams and that activation can be long lived and could potentially migrate through reuse/re-purposing of components, but no in the sense that the continued activation is dependent on the local presence of such a high energy source.